# How to enable scrolling a tall image inside fancybox?

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Using fancybox v2. I have a few images that are taller than the viewport. When the user selects a thumbnail, I want the full size image to open in fancybox BUT I don't want fancybox to scale the image. Instead, I want scrollbars to show up inside fancybox so the user can scroll the image vertically.

I went through all the possible settings but I am not able to figure out how to do this - if possible at all - because fancybox seems to scale and fit the image inside regardless of what I try.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: yes, images get a special treatment and always scaled. One option would to use the browser scrollbars (instead of inside fancybox) while setting fitToView false and maxWidth to 90%

Comment: That works, thank you!